# I think I found a bug in /etc/grub.d/10_linux

Tags: grub2, 20.04, zfs

The Ubuntu 20.04 installer supports a ZFS root filesystem, which works well
until an install or update involves touching the grub configuration.

I have tracked down what looks like the root cause in /etc/grub.d/10_linux

What is the best way to contact one of the developers that works on grub?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one easy way:

1. **Test the development release of Ubuntu to see if the bug is still there**. Lots of minor bugfixes don't get backported to older releases. If the bug is fixed, stop. Don't re-report a fixed problem. Instead, find the original bug report and request a [Stable Release Update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).
2. **Figure out which package provides that file**. In this example, you can see that the file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` is provided by the package `grub-common`

   ```
   $ dpkg -S /etc/grub.d/10_linux
   grub-common: /etc/grub.d/10_linux
   ```
3. **File a bug report against the appropriate package** using `ubuntu-bug <package_name>` and simply follow the prompts.
4. **After filing your bug report**, ensure you get e-mail on that bug, so you can answer questions by Triagers and Developers on how to reproduce the problem in their test environment. Also, volunteers willing to test the fixes are essential.

Comment: I have created Bug #1894101 and included the root cause and an example workaround patch.